# how to define index in angular material table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

how should I define an index variable when angular material table is used as ngFor is not used in this table.

I did search for it in the documentation but index is not mentioned any where in it.

```html
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

where and how do i define an index variable for the array that  I used in this table, so that I can bind the index value in my table itself.

Comment: Can you handle the index value and set it when you fetch the data from the API?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Can you add `index` to `let element; let i = index;"` as you'd do with `*ngFor`?

```xml
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"></mat-row>
```

Or like so:

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="index">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Index </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">{{i}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Working Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acdxje?file=app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: Works! But I'd love to know where this came from....how did you know there's a variable index available to be consumed? Can someone explain this further please?

Comment: Take care that it will repeat  per page if you enabled pagination

Comment: if you have pagination you can calculate row index like `{{this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize + i}}`

Comment: `let i=dataIndex` this is working for me.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, please remove "this" keyword and try as {{paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize + i}} and will work.!

Answer (score 134):

For anyone who has set the `multiTemplateDataRows` property of [mat-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable) to true, you can't use `index`. Instead you have use either `dataIndex` or `renderIndex`.

```xml
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = dataIndex;">{{i}}</mat-cell>
```

See https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12793

Comment: Take care that it will repeat per page if you enabled pagination

Answer (score 13):

For those who are facing problem with keeping the right index when using pagination which table has more than 1 page. It can be especially important when you have editable element, thus you're using a **routerLink** to add/edit/delete selected elements.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="title">
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Title</mat-header-cell>
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let book; let i = index;" fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="center center">
  <button mat-button [routerLink]="[i + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize)]" routerLinkActive="active"</button>
 </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

As well as

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

In essence, **i + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize)** is the solution, but it counts from **0**. If you'd like to index from **1**, simply make it **(i+1) + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize)**. Worth to note is that you really need the **#paginator** and **[pageSize]="VALUE"**.

Comment: `<td td mat-cell *matCellDef="let index = index">{{ (index + 1) + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize) }}</td>` works best for paginated data table. thanks.

Comment: `Worth to note is that you really need the #paginator and [pageSize]="VALUE".` This is the real key.

Answer (score 8):

From Angular 5 you can alias `index` to local variable `i` using `index as i`

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="rowIndex">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Index </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;index as i;"> {{ i }} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 8):

If someone using `<mat-paginator ../>`, then index can be interpreted as below

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i"> {{paginator.pageSize * paginator.pageIndex + i + 1}}</mat-cell>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using pagination in your mat-table,

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="index">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Index </mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i">
        {{tableOnePaginator.pageSize * tableOnePaginator.pageIndex + i + 1}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

In here, this tableOnePaginator is need to define in your ts component before using it. And make sure you have set that to your dataSource as follows.

```
this.dataSource.paginator = this.tableOnePaginator;
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you add index to let element; let i = index;" as you'd do with *ngFor?

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"></mat-row>
```

Also Add index column.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="index">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Index </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">{{i + 1}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using paginator and you want to place index with every page change then go with this below code;
In .HTML file:-

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Position">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> # </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i= index"> {{i + 1 +
     (thirdPaginator.pageIndex*thirdPaginator.pageSize) }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are use paginator try this:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Position </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"> {{(i+1) + (paginator.pageIndex*paginator.pageSize)}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

this working perfectly for Angular version 8.you must use #paginator and [pageSize]="VALUE"

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let indx = dataIndex">
```

When using the multiTemplateDataRows directive to support multiple rows for each data object, the context of ***matRowDef** is the same except that the **index** value is replaced by **dataIndex** and **renderIndex.**

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Index">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> # </th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i;">
      {{_paginator.pageSize * _paginator.pageIndex + i + 1}}    
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

Heading

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 14, unique declaration that worked in my case is:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = dataIndex">
```

In other parts of my app, `index as i` also works, but not always.
I heard that using `let i = index` is written in old versions of Angular