# get index of row in angular material table v5

Tags: angular, angular-material-5

I'm trying to get the index of row in table, in html, which has been implemented using angular material v5.2. Is there any method available to get the index?

The code for reference:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
     <button (click)="doSomething()"> Do something</button>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

The method doSomething is what needs index.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 156):

Using indexOf is an enormous waste of resources. The right way is initializing a variable with index's value, like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Num. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{i + 1}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

**UPDATE**:

If you are using **pagination** the index can be calculated this way:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Num. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index">
  {{this.paginator.pageIndex == 0 ? i + 1 : 1 + i + this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize}}
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. If you're not using the anything from your dataSource in this column (e.g. `element`), you don't need to declare it. You can just do `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index">{{i}}</td>`

Comment: `<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{i}}</td>`

This Works

Comment: One thing that baffles me is why on earth is half the answer in French?

Comment: @zgluis If we are using mat-paginator along with mat-table, how to accomplish the same ?

Comment: This is working You need to define paginator id we have used multiple paginations on the same HTML file


`<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index;">{{ this.TableTwoPaginator.pageIndex == 0 ?  i+1 : i+ 1 + this.TableTwoPaginator.pageIndex * this.TableTwoPaginator.pageSize}}</td>`


Thanks...!!!

Comment: `this.paginator.pageIndex == 0 ? i + 1 : 1 + i + this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize` can be shortened to simply `this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize + i + 1`

Answer (score 41):

Anyone using Angular6+ should use `let i = dataIndex` instead of `let i = index` as explained in this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12793#issuecomment-415356860).

Here's the HTML snippet

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Num. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = dataIndex">{{i + 1}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: `dataIndex` - this is the right answer!! Thank you! So many answers but only this one is valid.

Comment: This should definitely be the answer of the question.

Comment: This did not work for me with Angular 17, I had to stick to `index` otherwise I got no value.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the `filteredData` property of your `dataSource`, like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Header</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{dataSource.filteredData.indexOf(element)}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vfhb2)

With the @user3891850 solution(`let i = index;`), in case of pagination, the index will be the index in this page and not in the global object so you must be careful in case of pagination.
[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnt6sh)

Comment: This works `{{dataSource.filteredData.indexOf(element)}}`

Comment: That's great, I used {{dataSource.filteredData.indexOf(element)+1}} to avoid the value 0.
Thank u!!

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised why all of them are ok with using index. Don't they use pagination...  This is what we really need for paginated mat table..

Comment: Do you know how many times the render get executed and every time you want to lookup for the index? This leads to low performance on big tables.

Answer (score 11):

In case you run into this issue and you are using a `paginator` the index you get here:

```
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">{{i}}</td>
```

will be the current index displayed on the table. For instance, if you are on page 2 and your page size is 5, then the first index of the table will be 0 and not 5 (or the 6th item). So what you can do to get the true index is something like this:

```
index =
      this.paginator.pageIndex > 0
        ? index + this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize
        : index;
```

If the paginator is on page one, index doesn't change. Otherwise multiply the pageIndex by the pageSize and add it to the index.

Answer (score 7):

I know this post is old but the above solution didn't work for me.
instead if `let i = index;` try `let i = dataIndex` for latest version of mat-table check
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530994/in-angular-how-do-i-get-the-row-index-on-a-mat-table-with-expandable-content). Don't know if it's just for expandable table though

Comment: Worked on Angular 12

Answer (score 7):

increase position number in mat-table....

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="index">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sr.No </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let i=index"> {{i+1}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 6):

I found 2 cases when using Angular Material Table

- Using `*matCellDef="let row = index"` if the table has one-row template
- Using `*matCellDef="let row = dataIndex"` if the table has multiple row templates

Answer (score 1):

Include 'let i = index' in *matRowDef

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot, but for my case "indexOf" scenario doesn't work properly then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821027/11257333), and it does exactly what I need.

```
let i = index;
i + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  rindex:any;
  Cindex:any;

  show(){
    console.log("Column",this.Cindex,""+"Cell",this.rindex)

  }
  logIndex(j:any):void{
 this.Cindex=j

  }
  logIndex1(i:any):void{
    this.rindex=i

  }
```

```html
  <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns; index as i;" matColumnDef={{col}}>
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="">{{displayedColumnsNames[i]}}</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element  ; "(click)="logIndex1(i) "> {{element[col]}} </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns;sticky :true   " ></tr>
                  <tr  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;  let j=index; "(click)="[logIndex(j),show()] " ></tr>
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers but explain your answer a little in textual form: Why and how does it work, what makes it different to the other answers given?