# In Angular, how do I get the row index on a Mat-Table with expandable content?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, row

I have a page that uses a mat-table with expandable content. I need to be able to have a click event that records the row number of the table that I am clicking on.

Now, if I have a table without the expandable content I can successfully use the following in the html file:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"
    (click)="logIndex(i)">
```

and the following in the component file:

```
 logIndex(i)
  {
    console.log(i);
  }
```

but this doesn't work with expandable content. Here is a html file I am working with:
[Stackblitz HTML](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pee1l7-svccex?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

which contains

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;let i = index;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = element"
      (click)="logIndex(i)">
  </tr>
```

and returns "undefined".

This is a simple example. In my actual page I am using a MatTableDataSource as the datasource for the mat-table. I am aware that I could use `dataSource.filteredData.indexOf(element)` in this situation to get the row number but the mat-table also uses a mat-sort and sorting the table will still return the original row number, not the index of the row after sorting. Can I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: If you pass element in function so you will get current row object.

Comment: Hi Paresh. Were you talking about the position property? If so, sorry that was misleading. I've removed it and updated the link. If not, can you show me what you mean? I don't understand how passing the element would get me the row number.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Instead of using let i = index; Use let i = **dataIndex**

```
<tr mat-row 
    *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay; let i = dataIndex;"
  class="example-element-row"
  [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
  (click)="expandedElement = element"
  (click)="logIndex(i)">
```

Referenced answer from a [Github Material2 Issue Thread](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12793#issuecomment-415356860)

Comment: Thank-you. I've been stuck on this for way too long.

Comment: This works - [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648270/how-to-define-index-in-angular-material-table?rq=1 ]