# How to return single id from object in MatTable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a angular 8 application and I am using angular material with MatTableDatasource.

And I want to get the id from the selected object.

So I have this list:

```
0: {id: "e38e3a37-eda5-4010-d656-08d81c0f3353", family: "b2d72183-3cfc-4f49-bf71-0ed969f820f0",…}
1: {id: "126310fa-645e-40fb-f5a6-08d81b45f7e4", family: "120943ce-ed49-4aa1-a1d7-ab8e6f4bf18e",…}
2: {id: "a8fb7fe2-6301-4a16-4c67-08d81c15a41c", family: "48b152b8-20c7-4f10-b613-6314251564b6",…}
3: {id: "df386049-6da0-45b0-d659-08d81c0f3353", family: "fafb37c3-ee68-4cd5-8ecc-d6b553700c14",…}
4: {id: "e70940c1-2e29-4b4c-d657-08d81c0f3353", family: "90ecca9e-b70e-4ac0-b41d-a82a289e87a1",…}
5: {id: "bff0475b-0c34-4709-e9c1-08d7b5e43648", family: "0df5ab39-eab4-4ce8-b511-419028031012",…}
```

and so if you click on a row that I want to reuturn the id, so for example: e38e3a37-eda5-4010-d656-08d81c0f3353

So I try it like this:

```
   <ng-container matColumnDef="dupliceren">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef i18n>duplicate</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">

          <a
            mat-button
            mat-icon-button

            (click)="getRowId(row.id)"
            ><mat-icon>filter_none</mat-icon></a
          >
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

and ts script:

```
getRowId(rowId: EcheqDefinitionApi) {
    console.log(rowId.id);
  }
```

```
export interface EcheqDefinitionApi { 
    /**
     * Primary key of this version of an eCheq. Set by server.
     */
    id?: string;
    /**
     * All echeqs with the same family guid are versions of the same eCheq. Set by server.
     */
    family?: string;
    /**
     * Title of this version of an eCheq, visible to users.
     */
    title: string;
}
```

But if I try that. I get this error:

```
ListComponent.html:111 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ListComponent.push../src/app/echeq-definition/list/list.component.ts.ListComponent.getRowId (list.component.ts:69)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ListComponent.html:115)
    at handleEvent (core.js:19628)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20722)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20425)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:17077)
    at core.js:17524
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14134)
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

This is the constructor:

```
constructor(private i18n: I18n, private dialog: MatDialog, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const allDefinitions: EcheqDefinitionApi[] = route.snapshot.data['definitions'];
    this.isArchive = route.snapshot.data['isArchive'] || false;

    // Essentialy a group by family
    const latestFamilyDefinitions: {[family: string]: ListItem} = allDefinitions.reduce((accumulated: {[family: string]: ListItem}, i) => {
      const listItem = accumulated[i.family];
      if (!listItem) {
        accumulated[i.family] = new ListItem(i);
      } else {
        listItem.addToFamily(i);
      }
      return accumulated;
    }, {});
    this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource(Object.values(latestFamilyDefinitions));
  }
```

so if I do this:

```
  getRowId(rowId: ListItem) {
   const hallo =  this.route.snapshot.data['definitions'];
  }
```

it retuns all the definitions:

```
0: {id: "e38e3a37-eda5-4010-d656-08d81c0f3353", family: "b2d72183-3cfc-4f49-bf71-0ed969f820f0", title: "HelloThere", createdBy: "d9824535-c6b0-40cf-84e2-d9e37b02a5db", createdByName: "", …}
1: {id: "126310fa-645e-40fb-f5a6-08d81b45f7e4", family: "120943ce-ed49-4aa1-a1d7-ab8e6f4bf18e", title: "HelloThere", createdBy: "d9824535-c6b0-40cf-84e2-d9e37b02a5db", createdByName: "", …}
2: {id: "a8fb7fe2-6301-4a16-4c67-08d81c15a41c", family: "48b152b8-20c7-4f10-b613-6314251564b6", title: "hoi", createdBy: "d9824535-c6b0-40cf-84e2-d9e37b02a5db", createdByName: "", …}
3: {id: "df386049-6da0-45b0-d659-08d81c0f3353", family: "fafb37c3-ee68-4cd5-8ecc-d6b553700c14", titl
```

Comment: did you try to send row to the function and see what is the object?

Comment: Does this answer help you in resolving your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50292634/7743705. Ideally, you will have to extrapolate a couple of things from this to achieve your required outcome.

Comment: What exacly do you mean?

Comment: If I do this:  console.log(rowId); I also get back undefined

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity how did you initialize the datasource? please show code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, the problem is that you did

```
getRowId(rowId: EcheqDefinitionApi) {
console.log(rowId.id);
}
```

But you sent to the function this

```
(click)="getRowId(row.id)"
```

Meaning, you sent the string of the id to the function. Typescript doesn't yell at you about that, event though you told it the type is `EcheqDefinitionApi`.

Now, when you click on the row, the string id is sent to the function.
When you try to log the id of that string you get an error- because it does not contain an id!

How you can solve that:

- Send the row to the function- as in `getRowId(row: EcheqDefinitionApi)` and in the HTML: `(click)="getRowId(row)"`
- Use the string id accepted- as in `getRowId(rowId: string) { console.log(rowId); }` and in the HTML: `(click)="getRowId(row.id)"`

Good luck!