# How to set Serial Number in Mat-table angular 5

Tags: angular, material-design

I have used a mat-table in my angular app and have populated it successfully, but the original id's of the data are not serial wise and datas are filtered and only some data are to be displayed. Is there a way to add an auto incrementing serial no. My Html for the code:

```
    <mat-table #table2 [dataSource]="dataSource2" matSort>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="sn">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SN. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ index + 1 }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.description}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="start_time">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Start Time </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.start_time}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="end_time">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> End Time </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.end_time}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="total_pins">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total Pins </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.total_pins}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="total_cards">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total Cards </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.total_cards}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="remarks">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Remarks </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.remarks}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns2"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns2;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: what is `index` in your code ?

Comment: Have you viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49648270/9766215)?

Comment: that was the problem, i hadnt assigned index.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use this code in a row to get index -

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i+1}} </td>
```

Here is

## [forked working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajhrqc?file=app/table-filtering-example.html)

Comment: It works like a charm, but I got the issue with paginator, when I go to the next page it starts again from one. If I am showing 10 item per page then after goes to next page it starts with one instead of eleven. Please help.

Comment: Assigning index doesn't work for me in case of table with expandable rows. What is alternative for that?

Comment: It is not working when doing the pagination.

Answer (score 14):

**To get auto increment index value to the next pages.**

## ([Page Index] * [Page Size] + [row Index + 1])

**Table's td cell loop source code**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No.</th>
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; let i = index">
    {{ (paginatorRef.pageIndex * paginatorRef.pageSize) + (i + 1) }}
 </td>
</ng-container>
```

## mat-paginator source code

```
<mat-paginator
    fxFlex="100"
    #paginatorRef
    [length]="5"
    [pageSize]="5"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

> [ Note: Add local reference as #paginatorRef into your
> mat-paginator code ]

Comment: This answer is the correct one. Answers that mentions only "{{i+1}}" is partially correct, because that only works on first page, one the second and later pages it always starts from 1, which I guess a bit wrong information.

Comment: This answer only correct for this question

Answer (score 3):

## if you are using paginator from angular then

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; let i = index">
    {{ (paginatorRef.pageIndex * paginatorRef.pageSize) + (i + 1) }}
 </td>

<mat-paginator
    #paginatorRef>
</mat-paginator>
```

## if you are not using paginator and the whole table is in one page then

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i+1}} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an incremental serial number within ngFor loop i.e.

```
<meta-table *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="sn">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SN. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ i + 1 }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
</meta-table>
```

Comment: It is not working when doing the pagination.