# Row index is not available in Angular CDK table

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have a simple table like this

```html
<table cdk-table [dataSource]="doors" [multiTemplateDataRows]="true" class="table table-hover">
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="width">
    <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Width</th>
    <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row; let idx = index;">
      Index: [{{idx}}]
      <span *ngIf="idx === undefined">undefined</span>
      <span *ngIf="idx === null">null</span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="['width']"></tr>
  <tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; let i = index; columns: ['width']"></tr>
</table>
```

I need to access row index but it is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cknv1

Comment: Isn't `row - 1` your index?

Comment: No, row is the item from data source. I need an index of this item in data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `let idx = dataIndex;`

Since you are using `[multiTemplateDataRows]=true`.

From the source:

```
/**
 * Context provided to the row cells when `multiTemplateDataRows` is true. This context is the same
 * as CdkCellOutletRowContext except that the single `index` value is replaced by `dataIndex` and
 * `renderIndex`.
 */
```

Look [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12793) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Its the same question as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648270/how-to-define-index-in-angular-material-table?rq=1)

you should use dataIndex like this:

```
<tr cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; let i = dataIndex;; columns: ['width']"></tr>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, I've chosen @Korfoo 's answer because it is more informative.