# using index of item in angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i want to find index of elemnt in table in angular material . i write this code :

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">

        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ 'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element ; let i = index">
            <span class="icon" *ngIf="element.isHeading==true">
                <mat-icon *ngIf="element.parentId==null" (click)="openChild(element.id,i)">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
            </span> {{element.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <!-- <ng-container matColumnDef="courseTitle">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ 'LESSON.COURSE_TITLE' | translate }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" ktIsEllipsisActive> {{element.courseTitle }} </td>



    <ng-container matColumnDef="courseTitle">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ 'LESSON.CLASS' | translate }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" ktIsEllipsisActive> {{element.courseTitle }} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row;let i=index; columns: displayedColumns;"
        [ngClass]="'child'+row.parentId"
        [class.isChild]="row.parentId!==null && row.isHeading===false "></tr>

</table>
```

and i write this for find index :

```
*matCellDef="let element ; let i = index"
```

but every time it show me i is `undefined` .

how  can i access to index of item in `<td>`?

Comment: <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element of what?

Comment: @yazan i edit the question

Comment: Could your provide details about element in your ts file?

Comment: You will find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648270/how-to-define-index-in-angular-material-table/53525491

Comment: Not sure but it seems to be working fine here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xd55mx?file=app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: @HimanshuSingh i using that code but not worked

Comment: @lissettdm it not worked man

Comment: @kianoushdortaj can you replicate the issue on stackblitz and share the link because without having the issue in hand it is difficult to answer this

Answer (score 0):

Your iterator is incomplete. You are declaring an element variable in an unfinished for...of loop.

```
*matCellDef="let element ; let i = index"
```

Should have the keyword "of" after the "element" variable. After "of", there should be a reference to a collection (such as an array, for example). Otherwise, the element variable will have nowhere to pull information from.

If you're rendering table cells by binding them to an array in your typescript file, be sure to add that array's name to the end of that for...of loop.

```
*matCellDef="let element of yourArrayHere; let i = index"
```